# Jest with fetch-mock generating error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined when using on nodejs

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I'm almost sure it's my mistake, but I spent one entire day trying to solve and I've being failed .

I'm trying to configure the fetch-mock on node to use with jest. I tried a lot of things and the best result that I have is this:

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/824198/50566568-7b49e400-0d22-11e9-884f-89720899de3a.png

I'm sure my mock is working because if I pass it through parameter to the "Myclass.query" it works perfectly.

I'm also sure that the mock is arriving in my test file, because the mock function is present in the fetch module.

But... all together aren't working .

I created a very simple and small project to see this problem happening:

https://github.com/cesarjr/test-node-fetch

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

`Jest` uses the mock at `__mocks__/node-fetch.js` any time `node-fetch` is required during the test.

The problem is that [the first thing `fetch-mock` does is require `node-fetch`](https://github.com/wheresrhys/fetch-mock/blob/f4c828d78614bb0ae0e7f2e1e2de68623bd3d67b/src/server.js#L1).

This means that `Request` is not defined when it is set on the `config` [here](https://github.com/wheresrhys/fetch-mock/blob/f4c828d78614bb0ae0e7f2e1e2de68623bd3d67b/src/server.js#L15), so calling `prototype` on the undefined `Request` causes an error [here](https://github.com/wheresrhys/fetch-mock/blob/f4c828d78614bb0ae0e7f2e1e2de68623bd3d67b/src/lib/request-utils.js#L38).

Someone smarter than me might know how to force `Jest` to require the actual `node-fetch` when `fetch-mock` requires `node-fetch` in the mock for `node-fetch`, but from what I can see it doesn't look like it is possible.

---

Looks like you will have to delete the mock at `__mocks__/node-fetch.js` and pass `fetch` to your code, something like this:

myclass.js

```
class MyClass {
  static query(fetch, sessionId, query) {
    const url = 'https://api.foobar.com';

    const body = {
      sessionId,
      query
    };

    return fetch(url, {
      method: 'post',
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    })
      .then(res => res.json());
  }
}

module.exports = MyClass;
```

...then create the `sandbox` in your test and pass it to your code, something like this:

myclass.test.js

```
const fetch = require('fetch-mock').sandbox();
const MyClass = require('./myclass');

describe('MyClass', () => {
  describe('.query', () => {
    it('returns the response', () => {
      fetch.mock('*', {'result': {'fulfillment': {'speech': 'The answer'}}});

      expect.assertions(1);

      return MyClass.query(fetch, '123', 'the question').then((data) => {
        expect(data.result.fulfillment.speech).toBe('The answer');  // SUCCESS
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've now found a reliable way to combine fetch-mock and jest http://www.wheresrhys.co.uk/fetch-mock/#usageusage-with-jest

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where some `Date` functions were being mocked with `jest.fn` in order to avoid having today's date in each snapshot.

I guess - based on the answers above - that the mocked methods must have been used by jest itself before it was ready to mock them.

In my case, the mocks didn't actually need to be full jest mocks (i.e. `jest.fn((...params...) => ...body...)` ), just a plain mock function was sufficient (i.e. `(...params...) => ...body...` ), so changing this fixed it.