# How to mock (in jest) using an implementation which has the original implementation as a dependency

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

My library, [fetch-mock](https://github.com/wheresrhys/fetch-mock), has the library it provides a mock for, [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch), as a dependency.

As jest mocks globally, this means that when `fetch-mock` attempts to access properties of the original `node-fetch` implementation, the properties are undefined because it circularly points to `fetch-mock`  (at least this, is my diagnosis of the [problem](https://github.com/wheresrhys/fetch-mock/issues/407))

Does this diagnosis seem correct, and if so, how can one require the original implementation of a module in a mock when using jest?

Comment: How about [jest.requireActual](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestrequireactualmodulename) helper? You can see if you make some headway with it

Comment: Cezinha asked [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54000152/jest-with-fetch-mock-generating-error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-prototyp) here a few days ago, this was my [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54029024/10149510).

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Thanks - I'll explore if I can use that somehow

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors Also thanks. Ideally I can get requireActual to work so that my users can just use fetch-mock with jest like any other module, but will add your pattern to the docs if it fails

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Problem solved http://www.wheresrhys.co.uk/fetch-mock/#usageusage-with-jest